# Enable programmatic billing for Amazon AWS through API (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Was wondering if anyone knew how if it was possible to enable programmatic billing for Amazon AWS through the API?  I have not found anything on this and I even went broader and looked for billing preferences or account settings through API and still had not luck.  I assume the API does not have this functionality but I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no API for doing this.  You have to log into your billing preference page and set it up there.  I agree that an API would be a great feature to add.